# Cannot root Verizon Galaxy S5 with towelroot

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have downloaded towelroot `tr.apk` for my Galaxy S5 from Verizon which I purchased recently.

I have heard of people having success with towelroot on their S5 devices bit for some reason I have been unsuccessful so far in rooting my device.

If I press the "makeitra1n" button I receive an error message saying my phone is not supported.

I did some research and found you could change the settings of the program

This article supplies instructions to change the modstrings : http://www.naldotech.com/how-to-fix-towelroot-phone-isnt-supported-problem/

But after trying all codes I still have no success, occasionally I get another message asking if my device is connected to the internet.

has anyone else shared this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vulnerability towelroot used has been fixed within Android 4.4.2. Check your version.
Plus, as you can read [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2783157&page=524), geohot, developer of towelroot, now works for Google, so probably there won't be updates.

I wouldn't recommend any other root method: it could invalidate your warranty. See [this article](http://omegadroid.co/wanted-knox-void-warranty-0x1/).

Comment: What about for S5 devices on Verizon with unlocked bootloaders?